# how to change the value of the param name in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my Xslt template part:here i want to change the scope in to index value.How i do it?

```
<xsl:template match="//w:body/w:sdt/w:sdtContent/w:p/child::* ">

    <xsl:param name = "scope"/>
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)"/>
    <xsl:if test = "$index &lt;= $scope">
      <Paragraph>
        <xsl:attribute name="index">
          <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="TOC">TRUE</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//w:t"/>
      </Paragraph>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>
```

Plz Guide me to get this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-assign to a parameter. What do you want to do with this? There is usually a way round it.

Comment: Gillbert: I want to increase the index value one by one while each time this template called.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you cannot change or modify value of param. In most cases you can avoid this or emulate using recursion.